# How to call a list style parameter in snakemake

Tags: r, snakemake

I wrote some R scripts, and I 'd like to use `snakemake` to integrate them to an analysis pipeline. I almost finish this pipeline, except one of the R script. In this R script, one of the parameters is a list, like this:

```
group=list(A=c("a","b","c"),B=c("d","e"),C=c("f","g","h"))
```

I don't know how to call this kind of parameters in `snakemake`.

The R script and `snakemake` script I wrote are as follow:

### R script:

```
library(optparse)
library(ggtree)
library(ggplot2)
library(colorspace)

# help doc  

option_list=list(
    make_option("--input",type="character",help="<file> input file"),
    make_option("--output",type="character",help="<file> output file"),
    make_option("--families",type="character",help="<list> a list containing classified families"),
    make_option("--wide",type="numeric",help="<num> width of figure"),
    make_option("--high",type="numeric",help="<num> height of figure"),
    make_option("--labsize",type="numeric",help="<num> size of tip lable")
)

opt_parser=OptionParser(usage="\n\nName: cluster_vil.r",
                        description="\nDescription: This script is to virualize the result of cluster analysis.
                        \nContact: huisu<hsu@kangpusen.com>
                        \nDate: 9.5.2019",
                        option_list=option_list,
                        epilogue="Example: Rscript cluster_vil.r --input  mega_IBSout_male.nwk
                               --output NJ_IBS_male.ggtree.pdf
                               --families list(Family_A=c('3005','3021','3009','3119'),Family_B=c('W','4023'),Family_C=c('810','3003'),Family_D=c('4019','1001','4015','4021'),Family_E=c('4017','3115'))
                               --wide 18
                               --high 8
                               --labsize 7"
)

opt=parse_args(opt_parser)

input=opt$input
output=opt$output
families=opt$families
wide=opt$wide
high=opt$high
labsize=opt$labsize

# start plot

nwk=read.tree(input)

tree=groupOTU(nwk, families)

pdf(file=output,width=wide,height=high) # 18,8 for male samples; 12,18 for all samples

ggtree(tree,aes(color=group),branch.length='none') + geom_tiplab(size=labsize) +
    theme(legend.position=("left"),legend.text=element_text(size=12),legend.title=element_text(size=18),
          legend.key.width=unit(0.5,"inches"),legend.key.height=unit(0.3,"inches")) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=c("black", rainbow_hcl(length(families)))) +
    theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(2,4),'cm'))

dev.off()
```

### snakemake:

```
rule cluster_virual:
    input:
        nwk="mega_IBS.nwk",
    output:
        all="mega_IBS.pdf",
    params:
        fam=collections.OrderedDict([('Family_A',['3005','3021','3009','3119']),
                                     ('Family_B',['W','4023']),
                                     ('Family_C',['810','3003']),
                                     ('Family_D',["4019","1001","4015","4021"]),
                                     ('Family_E',["4017","3115"])])
    message:
        "====cluster analysis virualization===="
    shell:
        "Rscript Rfunction/cluster_vil.r " 
        "--input {input.nwk} "
        "--output {output.all} "
        "--families {params.fam} "
        "--wide 12 "
        "--high 18 "
        "--labsize 3"
```

So, I want to know how to properly call the write the parameter `fam` in snakemake.

Answer (score 2):

I think in python/snakemake you can use `OrderedDict` to represent an R list. So:

```
params:
    fam=list(A=c('a','b','c'),B=c('d','e'),C=c('f','g','h'))
```

Would be:

```
params:
    fam= collections.OrderedDict([('A', ['a', 'b', 'c']), 
                                  ('B', ['d', 'e', 'f']),
                                  ('C', ['h', 'g'])])
```

Of course, add `import collections` to the top of your snakemake file (or wherever you want to import the collections module).

Comment: In Python 3.6, dicts are ordered. From 3.7 above it is in the spec even, not just an implementation detail. So very soon, ordereddict is not needed anymore :) ! But upvote, because your answer is the correct one.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat thanks, good know. Actually, I think my original answer was somewhat misleading as I was building the OrderedDict from a dict. So the order of keys would have been unpredictable. Better to build the OrderedDict from a list of tuples (edited now).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I tried it, but my program still doesn't work. The error message is as following: 

/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `set -euo pipefail;  Rscript Rfunction/cluster_vil.r --input mega_IBS.M.nwk --output mega_IBS.M.pdf --families OrderedDict([('Family_A', ['3005', '3021', '3009', '3119']),...., ('Family_E', ['4017', '3115'])]) --wide 12 --high 18 --labsize 3'                     so, what's the problem?

Comment: @Luna How are you executing `Rfunction/cluster_vil.r`? Via the script directive or as the shell directive? Maybe edit your post to show the entire rule.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have updated my post. Please have a look of it.